# Appending to List after Pandas if else statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to append the `time` value to `plotList` wherever the `dup` column value is `False`.

The DF =

```
 lat                time      trip_id     diff  shifted  Segment    dup 
-7.12040 2015-12-24 02:03:10  18060.0  0.00003  0.00000        1  False 
-7.12043 2015-12-24 02:03:12  18060.0  0.00000  0.00003        2  False 
-7.12043 2015-12-24 02:03:14  18060.0  0.00003  0.00003        2   True 
-7.12046 2015-12-24 02:03:16  18060.0  0.00003  0.00003        2   True 
-7.12049 2015-12-24 02:03:19  18060.0  0.00003  0.00000        3  False 
-7.12052 2015-12-24 02:03:22  18060.0  0.00000 -0.00473        4  False
```

The Code =

```
plotList=[]
def pullLine(row):
    if row['dup'] == False:
        plotList.append(row['time'])
pullLine(df)
```

I had thought this might work but I get the error that `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`

Can anyone explain a) what is going on here, and b) what I can do to avoid? I don't understand how asking if something is `False` can be ambiguous.

Many thanks.

Comment: what is `row`? can you make a complete example that generates your data and applies the `pullLine` function?

Comment: `df['time'][~df['dup']]` should work? Alternatively, you need to use apply: `df.apply(pullLine, axis = 1)` will work with your `plotList` as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess you can do it this way:

```
plotList = df.loc[df['dup'] == False, 'time'].values
```

you're passing the whole DF as a parameter to your function, but are treating it as one row...

depending on what do you want to get - array or list:

```
In [167]: df.loc[df['dup'] == False, 'time'].values
Out[167]:
array(['2015-12-24 02:03:10', '2015-12-24 02:03:12', '2015-12-24 02:03:19',
       '2015-12-24 02:03:22'], dtype=object)

In [168]: df.loc[df['dup'] == False, 'time'].tolist()
Out[168]:
['2015-12-24 02:03:10',
 '2015-12-24 02:03:12',
 '2015-12-24 02:03:19',
 '2015-12-24 02:03:22']
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just filter on the `dup` column, using the negation `~` because you are filtering for False.

```
>>> df[~df.dup].time
0    2015-12-24 02:03:10
1    2015-12-24 02:03:12
4    2015-12-24 02:03:19
5    2015-12-24 02:03:22
Name: time, dtype: object
```

If you really want it in a list format:

```
df[~df.dup].time.tolist()
['2015-12-24 02:03:10',
 '2015-12-24 02:03:12',
 '2015-12-24 02:03:19',
 '2015-12-24 02:03:22']
```